# What’s wrong with the following induction proof?

Tags: algorithms, induction, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, fake-proofs

For $n = 2^i$ which is a power of 2, we might define
\begin{equation}
T(n) = \left\{
             \begin{array}{lr}
             2 \cdot T(\frac{n}{2}) + 32  \cdot n & n > 2 \\
             2 &  n = 2
             \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

The following wrong proof shows $T(n) = O(n\log{(n)}).$ I want to know what is the error.

- Inductive Hypothesis: $T(n) = O(n\log{(n)}).$
- Base case: $T(2) = 2 = O(1) = O(2log(2))$
- Inductive Step:

  - Suppose that $T(n) = O(nlog(n))$ for $n < k$.
  - Then $T(k) = 2 \cdot T(\frac{k}{2}) + 32 \cdot k$ by definition
  - So $T(k) = 2 \cdot O(\frac{k}{2} \log(\frac{k}{2})) + 32 \cdot k$ by induction
  - But that’s $T(k) = O(k\log(k))$ for all n, so the I.H. holds for $n = k.$
- Conclusion:

  - By induction, $T(n) = O(n\log{(n)})$ for all n.

Comment: That "base case" does not make sense. It is true that $c(n)=O(1)$ where $c$ is a constant function of $n$. But here you cannot take for granted that $c(n)$ is constant, while $c(1)$   is not a function and has no $O$ asymptotics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing an induction proof of a big-oh result,
you have to assume that a particular constant works
for $n$ and show that the same constant works
for $n+1$.

In this case, you have to show that
$T(n) < c n \log(n)$
implies
$T(n+1) < c (n+1) \log(n+1)$.

Work this through and see what condition
$c$ must satisfy.
If you get a contradiction, then the big-oh condition does not hold.

Comment: This is already a helpful answer, but I would like to add one more thing for the OP: with the flawed logic (when you don't take care of coefficients), it is possible to have a much more flawed proofs, where the error is more obvious. Look at this: set $a_n=n$ and "prove" that $a_n=O(1)$ i.e. $a_n$ is bounded: $a_1=1=O(1)$, and $a_{n+1}=a_n+1=O(1)+O(1)=O(1)$ (sum of two bounded sequences is bounded isn't it?)